# Make grep stop after first NON-matching line

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to use grep to go through some logs and only select the most recent entries.  The logs have years of heavy traffic on them so it's silly to do

```
    tac error.log | grep 2012
    tac error.log | grep "Jan.2012"
```

etc.

and wait for 10 minutes while it goes through several million lines which I already know are not going to match.  I know there is the `-m` option to stop at the first match but I don't know of a way to make it stop at first non-match.  I could do something like `grep -B MAX_INT -m 1 2011` but that's hardly an optimal solution.

Can grep handle this or would awk make more sense?

Comment: If you're willing to be a little ad-hoc about it, you could try `tail -n N' to extract the N most recent lines before piping it through grep to eliminate any not from this year.

Comment: I'd use awk or (actually) perl - why not?

Comment: Why are you allowing your log files to grow so big? Sounds like you need to find out about log rotation.

Comment: Your first sentence doesn't match the rest of the post: If you really wanted just "the most recent entries," you wouldn't need to stop searching. And there really isn't any way to get `grep` or any other program to *reliably* skip the correct amount of lines without reading them or knowing how many bytes you need to skip.

Comment: @l0b0 the point is that the first K lines all match a known pattern (a timestamp) and the remaining N-K do not.  Obviously I have to parse the first K lines, it's the remaining N-K that I want to avoid dealing with.

Comment: Ah, because you're using `tac`. I wouldn't bet money on it, but I think it would be much faster to `grep` directly than to `tac | [exclude the last N-K lines] | grep | tac` to get the lines back in the right sequence after searching.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using `awk` like this:

```
tac error.log | awk '{if(/2012/)print;else exit}'
```

This should exit as soon as a line not matching 2012 is found.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution in python:

```
# foo.py
import sys, re
for line in sys.stdin:
    if re.match(r'2012', line):
        print line,
        continue
    break
```

you@host> tac foo.txt | python foo.py

Comment: Useless Use of Cat. Just use `python foo.py foo.txt`.

Comment: I think he meant `tac foo.txt | python foo.py`

Comment: @triplee this (python foo.py foo.txt) does not work, since the snippets reads from stdin.

Comment: Then the proper way to avoid a Useless Cat is `python foo.py <foo.txt` ... But as noted the script requires a `tac` so it's not pertinent here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `grep` supports this.

But here is my "why did we have `awk` again" answer:

```
tail -n `tac biglogfile | grep -vnm1 2012 | sed 's/:.*//' | xargs expr -1 +` biglogfile
```

Note that this isn't going to be exact if your log is being written to.

Comment: Could you explain the sed and xargs part? I understand the rest of it.  Also, I don't think that the wording of the question implies that any solution must include grep, just that that's where I'm starting from.

Comment: Just try it out piecewise to see what the parts are for ... but OK: `grep -n` prints the line number with the matching lines, `sed` leaves just the line number, `xargs expr` decreases it by 1.

Answer (score 1):

The excellent [one-line scripts for `sed`](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt) page to the rescue:

```
# print section of file between two regular expressions (inclusive)
sed -n '/Iowa/,/Montana/p'             # case sensitive
```

In other words, you should be able to do the following:

```
sed -n '/Jan 01 2012/,/Feb 01 2012/p' error.log | grep whatevs
```

Comment: Great link, but won't that still go through the whole file?

Comment: Yes, but depending on how long and how precise you can make the regex, it can be very fast.

Comment: It's hardly going to be faster than the same search with `grep`.

Comment: @tripleee: It's obviously only going to be faster *if* there is data *after* the first `Feb 01 2012` line, but that's the assumption based on the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that parses the user's dot-plan file and stops at the first non-matching line:

```bash
PID=$$
while read ln; do
  echo $ln | {
    if grep "^[-*+] " >/dev/null; then
      # matched
      echo -e $ln
    elif grep "^[#]" >/dev/null; then
      # ignore comment line
      :
    else
      # stop at first non-matching line
      kill $PID
    fi
  }
done <$HOME/.plan
```

Of course this approach is considerably slower than if Grep reads the lines but at least you can incorporate several cases (not just the non-match).

For more complex scripts, it is worth noting that Bash can also apply regular expressions to variables, i.e. you can also do completely without `grep`.